# Company offered a lower pay than initially discussed

Tags: software-industry, new-job, negotiation, unprofessional-behavior

I've been in discussions with a new company lately, and after our first discussion we have agreed on a range of salary. Then I have passed all the interviews/assessments they had; the feedback from them was positive. After the final interview, they accepted me. The issue is that they proposed me a salary 28% lower than the minimum we first agreed on, invoking the fact that I don't have enough years of experience, yet they saw my CV from the first negotiation.

I didn't consider that fair at all, and turned down the offer. I'm curious on your opinion on this situation.

How would you handle this kind of situation?

Comment: I have added the question.

Answer (score 8):

When a company comes in with a low offer, you have three choices: accept, decline, or negotiate.

> How would you handle this kind of situation?

If I were really excited about the job otherwise, I would negotiate. If that hits my minimum compensation bar, I accept, otherwise I'd decline.

If I felt that they were not negotiating in good faith but tried to pull a bait & switch I would decline no matter what. Live is too short to waste time on bad companies and/or bad offers.

Comment: While to some extent I'd agree with negotiating if the offer were "a bit" below my minimum, 30% is far too big a number.

Comment: What's the harm in trying? I agree that it's a long shot, but all it's going to cost you is a phone call.

Comment: @PhilipKendall 30% is a big number *if* OP is offered the same position/level as they discussed initially. There is a non-zero chance that they resume and the current position name suggested much higher experience than was found during interviews. Indeed since OP did not mentioned that we need to assume they got such a low offer for the exact pay level/position they discussed initially and call it "low ball offer".

Answer (score 2):

If you are desperate for a job, take it to have money coming in, and immediately start searching for another job. Make sure you can quit at any time during the probation period. Offering 28% less than you asked for and than was accepted is a very very big red flag and it means you owe them nothing.

If you are not desperate I would say what you want is not negotiating but stating the salary that you want. Not your lower range, but what you want. And then you see what happens. Don’t go below what you want because they play mind games.